# EMF file(.so) debugging, symbol not found VTable error

Tags: c++, solaris

In Solaris I have an exe file as per the guideline I need to add a shared library (.so) to extend the functionality. I have created a lthmyplugin.so file and added as described. Now the utlity run perfectly fine untill it calls my function After calling my function it fails.

Questions:

1. Is there any way to debug?
2. When I run the command truss it identifies aa.so

Also ldd -d lthmyplugin.so  show no error except

```
    symbol not found: __1cIMyPluginG__vtbl_         (./lthmyplugin.so)    
    symbol not found: __1cIThPluginG__vtbl_         (./lthmyplugin.so)    
    symbol not found: __1cOThLocalOptionsG__vtbl_           (./lthmyplugin.so)    
    symbol not found: __1cJThOptionsG__vtbl_                (./lthmyplugin.so)
```

Can this cause the programme to fail?

fyi, I have not used and any virtual function,constructors or destructors

What does this mean symbol not found: _*1cIThPluginG*_vtbl_  ?

Thanks,

Comment: Try running the name through `cppfilt`. I'll be the vtable (virtual function dispatch table) for that class.

Comment: @Rup cppfilt     is not available is there any other option

Comment: Should be c++filt, not cppfilt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [nm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nm_%28Unix%29) tool to see the functions exposed by the so file. You can call:

```
nm -g lthmyplugin.so
```

... To see what functionality it exposes.

Besides that, given you've tagged this as C++, I'm going to take a stab and ask: did you specify a C style calling convention? If you didn't, it will mangle the names making them ugly, unreadable and in 99.9% of cases, unfindable. You can tell gcc not to mangle your functions by adding **__attribute__((cdecl))**, like so:

```
int not_mangled(int some_arg) __attribute__((cdecl))
{
    return some_arg * 3;
}
```